# angularjs tooltip within ng-repeat causes multiple evaluation of expression

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, tooltip, popover, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've built a table with angular's ng-repeat directives.  So there are a set of nested loops.  Then, for each cell in the table I enable a popover like so:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in columns">
  <div popover="{{popVal(row, col)}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-append-to-body="true">
    {{ regularVal(row, col) }}
  </div>
</td>
```

I log to the console from within the popVal() function and lo', it is called repeatedly, once per row,col combo for Every Cell the mouse enters.

This is not the behavior I desire.  The function is primarily being used just as a way to supply the row, col parameters.   How do I tell the popover or tooltip to be less aggressive with its $apply (or $observe) behavior?

Comment: Please add your `popover` directive `popVal()` function?  A jsfiddle or plunker showing the problem would also be appreciated.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/bwzSnUfWXBMlreKwYdWX

Comment: i don't find zScoreValue called ever in your plunker??

Comment: I edited it to cache the computed values.  Thought that'd "fix" the problem.  Turns out... after using a larger dataset, it does not fix things.  Still slow as a dog.